# Use bash to cluster based on one column of a line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

The input is as below

```
A  20  240
A  15  150
B  65  210
B  80  300
C  90  400
C  34  320
```

For each category (labelled as A,B,C..in the 1st column), I'd like to find the minimum as well as maximum numbers (as biggest range). So expect to see:

```
A  15  240
B  65  300
C  34  400
```

So how could I do using bash?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and then have bash call awk once you write the trivial awk script to do that job.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk '
    !($1 in min) { min[$1] = $2; max[$1] = $3; next }
    {
        min[$1] = ( $2 < min[$1] ? $2 : min[$1] )
        max[$1] = ( $3 > max[$1] ? $3 : max[$1] )
    } 
    END {
        for(x in min) print x, min[x], max[x]
}' file
A 15 240
B 65 300
C 34 400
```

We iterate each line and assign min and max values to a map that has first column as the key. In the END block we iterate the hash and print out the key and values from both maps.

Comment: You have just provided a free coding service

Comment: The community provides guidelines on what questions should be answered. A free coding service may encourage users to come back with questions with no effort at all, I'm afraid and you agree I guess.

Comment: Given the input lines `A 0 100` and `A 10 90`, the output is `A 10 100`, in which the minimum value is incorrect (I'd expect `A 0 100`).  The asymmetry between the minimum and maximum code is also a bit surprising.  Given the inputs `B -30 -20` and
`B -20 -10`, the output is `B -30 0`, whereas I'd expect `B -30 -10`.  I think you'll need to test `if ($1 in min) { …more or less as now… } else { min[$1] = $2; max[$1] = $3; }`.  Granted, it works on the sample data OK.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler. Have updated the code to fix the issue reported by your tests. I think it was the initialization problem. Hopefully should take care of other edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make an other solution (as a workaround) of the side affect of the unset variables in awk.
(May be this is a little bit more optimized.)

cat min_max

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
    NF!=3 || $2 $3 ~ "[^0-9-]" {next;}           # short filter
    min[$1]=="" {min[$1]=$2; max[$1]=$3; next;}  # first occur a given ID--> set min&max,read nxt ln
    min[$1]>$2  {min[$1]=$2;}                    # other occur IDs--> refresh min if required
    max[$1]<$3  {max[$1]=$3;}                    # refreshing max if required 
    END {for(x in min)printf("%-2s %5d %5d\n", x, min[x], max[x]);}
' $1
```

cat in4

```
A  20  240
B  65  210
C  90  400
A  15  150
C  34  320
E  -30  -20
D   0  100
B  80  300
D  10   90
E  -20 -10
```

./min_max in4

```
A     15   240
B     65   300
C     34   400
D      0   100
E    -30   -10
```

This bash code produces the same.

cat min_max2

```
#!/bin/bash
(($#!=1))&& { echo "Usage $0 inpfile"; exit 1; }
declare -A min max                                   # define associative arrays
while read id mn mx; do
   [[ ${min[$id]+any} == "" ]] && { min[$id]=$mn; max[$id]=$mx; continue; } # parameter extension
   (( ${min[$id]} > $mn )) && min[$id]=$mn
   (( ${max[$id]} < $mx )) && max[$id]=$mx
done <$1
for i in ${!min[@]}; do printf "%-2s %5d %5d\n" $i ${min[$i]} ${max[$i]}; done
```

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. In my output was a `"" 0 0` line and without thinking I put the `delete min [""]`. Now I know it was caused by an extra blank line at the end of my input file. Now I put a short filter line in the script.

Comment: You're welcome but that doesn't seem necessary as the OP almost certainly doesn't have blank or any other badly formatted lines in his/her input files.